# R java io unchecked io exception error

Tags: java, r, exception, io, rjava

I am running R studio with R version 3.4.1 and java version 1.8.0_131
I am trying to run a function I created and I am getting these errors:

I get this error when I run the specific function

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

I get this error when I run the entire script

```
 Error in ._jobjRef_dollar(x[["jobj"]], name) : 
      no field, method or inner class called '.when'
```

I am wondering if anyone may have an idea as to what is causing these errors, before I post the function. It is pretty long. It is essentially opening multiple files and reading them as tables. Each path is correct and it works individually.

Comment: "*Before I post the function*" - Always include relevant information. Format it to be more appealing if needed (include a TL;DR section at the top).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use `.when` somewhere in your script, however there is no such method for `.when`.

The issue could be that one of your libraries (`R`?) is an older version than the documentation you are using, or the `.when` call never existed in the first place.

The easiest way to fix this is to search and find out where `.when` is being called in your code, and then check if there is another method you can use instead, or if you just need to update to a newer library.

Add a bit of debugging code to print to console between opening each file and between reading them to the tables, that way you can at least see how far along your code gets before it fails.

For reference on where the error is called, you can take a look at the source for `rJava` here:
https://github.com/cran/rJava/blob/master/R/reflection.R

Specifically note your error in the last else block when rJave attempts to look for a function, but cannot find it:

```
### syntactic sugar to allow object$field and object$methods(...)
### first attempts to find a field of that name and then a method
._jobjRef_dollar <- function(x, name) {
    if (hasField(x, name) ){
        .jfield(x, , name)
    } else if( hasJavaMethod( x, name ) ) {
        function(...) .jrcall(x, name, ...)
    } else if( hasClass(x, name) ) {
        cl <- .jcall( x, "Ljava/lang/Class;", "getClass" )
        inner.cl <- .jcall( "RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Class;", "getClass", cl, name, FALSE ) 
        new("jclassName", name=.jcall(inner.cl, "S", "getName"), jobj=inner.cl)
    } else if( is.character(name) && length(name) == 1L && name == "length" && isJavaArray(x) ){
        length( x )
    } else {
        stop( sprintf( "no field, method or inner class called '%s' ", name ) ) 
    }
}
```